# Symfony2 manage multiple databases (from other framework)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem. My client wants to have a website in one symfony framework package and the CMS integrated in the other Symfony framework (Service Panel of the company).

So, we have Symfony A and B.

Now that there is a blog on the website (Symfony A) among a few other dynamic pages. All the Delete, add and update stuff needs to go into the service panel (Symfony B) with forms and such.

I know I can use multiple Entity Managers, but that'll only work if the website bundle is placed in the service panel framework (Symfony B), because of the mappings. I think it isn't possible, but they really want to have the CMS in their Service panel and the website in another symfony framework instance.

Is there a 'remote' solution, so that Symfony B (service panel) can change and manage the database of the website (Symfony A) **without** migrating the website bundle (Symfony A) into Symfony B? The website will run on the same machine as the service panel will. Only difference is they are completely separated of each other.

If I'm not clear enough, please tell me. I'm trying to be as clear as possible.

Hope somebody is able to help me with the issue.

Comment: I think what you want to do is to expose Symfony A functionality via a Web RESTlike API.

Comment: @Cerad: Yes, that would be the way to go. I only don't know how to do it, because of the entities involved :(

Answer (score 0):

So let's say we want to update a blog.

Symfony A would process these requests:

GET /blog/42 - Returns json rep of blog 42

PUT /blog/42 - Accepts and updates blog 42

Easy enough.  FOSRestBundle and JMSSerializerBundle can help with some of the plumbing.

So Symfony B uses curl (probably) to GET /blog/42 and converts the json data to a php array.

At this point you have a major decision.  If the entities are simple and stable the Symfony B could just use the array representation.  Symfony forms accept arrays no problem.  So this maybe all you need.

If however you want to convert the array data into a real Blog object that matches Symfony A then you need to make some more decisions.  The Symfony A entities are really just plain objects.  You could tweak Symfony B's autoload so it can see the Symfony A entities.  So B can get the entities from A (and then map the array data to the entities) without having any direct links.  Autoload just needs to know where the Symfony A entities live.

Or you could go one step further and make a BlogModelBundle in which the blog entities (without any doctrine stuff) are defined.  You would then have both applications load this bundle.  The A app would then extend the model and add the doctrine 2 stuff.  The B app would just hydrate the models using json.  This is probably the best approach for the long term.